# Can't restore slave replication

Tags: mysql, debian, sh

While importing a mysqldump this error is returned while importing

```
# sh restore_db_replication.sh
Warning: A partial dump from a server that has GTIDs will by default include the GTIDs of all transactions, even those that changed suppressed parts of the database. If you don't want to restore GTIDs, pass --set-gtid-purged=OFF. To make a complete dump, pass --all-databases --triggers --routines --events.
dynaccount_dump.sql.gz                                                                    100%  265MB  97.4MB/s   00:02
mysql: [Warning] Using a password on the command line interface can be insecure.
mysql: [Warning] Using a password on the command line interface can be insecure.
ERROR 1776 (HY000) at line 31: Parameters MASTER_LOG_FILE, MASTER_LOG_POS, RELAY_LOG_FILE and RELAY_LOG_POS cannot be set when MASTER_AUTO_POSITION is active.
96.0KiB 0:00:00 [4.93MiB/s] [>                                                                             ]  0%
mysql: [Warning] Using a password on the command line interface can be insecure.
```

The script

```
#!/bin/sh

slave_pass='xxx'

master_host='server.com'
master_pass='xxx'

ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no root@$master_host 'mysqldump -u root -p'"$master_pass"' --master-data --single-transaction --hex-blob --routines --triggers --events --quick --add-drop-database --extended-insert --databases name-of-db | gzip > /root/dump.sql.gz'

scp -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no root@$master_host:/root/dump.sql.gz /root

mysql -u root_slave -p$slave_pass -e "stop slave; CHANGE MASTER TO MASTER_HOST='$master_host', MASTER_USER='repl', MASTER_PASSWORD='$master_pass', MASTER_PORT=3306, MASTER_AUTO_POSITION=1; reset master;"

pv /root/dump.sql.gz | gunzip | mysql -u root_slave -p$slave_pass
mysql -u root_slave -p$slave_pass -e "start slave"

echo "\nShow slave status? [Y/n]"
read SHOW_STATUS

if [ "$SHOW_STATUS" = "y" ] || [ "$SHOW_STATUS" = "" ]; then
    mysql -u root_slave -p$slave_pass -e "show slave status\G;"
fi
```

Answer (score 1):

The error is due to the fact that GTID replication is set to OFF

and MASTER_AUTO_POSITION=1

and you did not reset the slave after stopping it.

The solution is one of the following:

(1) If you want slave to start reading from the point when this backup is created then do:

In mysqldump command (line 8in the script):

```
--set-gtid-purged=ON
```

After "stop slave;" in line 12 of the script where you have:

mysql -u root_slave -p$slave_pass -e "stop slave;

```
reset slave;
```

---

(2) If you want slave to start reading from the beginning

In line 12

Also after stop slave add:

```
reset slave;
```

And

Change:

```
MASTER_AUTO_POSITION=1
```

To:

```
MASTER_AUTO_POSITION=0
```